# Why does removing the 'WHERE product =' clause in this query not show all products?

Tags: database, catalogsearch

I'm doing a code review for a search engine extension and am testing this query on my database:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(value) FROM catalog_category_product_index 
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_text vc 
ON category_id = vc.entity_id 
WHERE product_id = 5281 AND vc.attribute_id = 484
```

The results are:

```
product_id   SUM(value)
5281         24000
```

However, when I remove the product_id = 5281 clause and run this:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(value) FROM catalog_category_product_index 
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_text vc 
ON category_id = vc.entity_id 
WHERE vc.attribute_id = 484
```

I expect a list of all products with their corresponding values. Instead, I get this:

```
product_id   SUM(value)
4871         2143200
```

I'm obviously missing something, and it's probably something obvious. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUM is an **aggregate** function. Appending a `GROUP BY product_id` should give the expected result.